# Login with Google using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-api, google-signin

```
$scope.authenticateGoogle = function(google) {

        var params = {
            'clientid':'something',
            'cookiepolicy':'single_host_origin',
            'callback': function(result){
                if(result['status']['signed_in']){
                  gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
                    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                        'userId': 'me'
                    });
                    request.execute(function(resp){
                        $scope.$apply(function(){

                           //

                        });
                    });
                 }); 
               }
            },
            'approvalprompt':'force',
            'scope':'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
        };
        gapi.auth.signIn(params);
   };
```

Users land on the permissions screen upon every login.

How can I fix this code?

Google says that for basic information it does not require approval.

Please guide me.

Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're good try remove 'approvalprompt':'force',

```
$scope.authenticateGoogle = function(google) {

        var params = {
            'clientid':'something',
            'cookiepolicy':'single_host_origin',
            'callback': function(result){
                if(result['status']['signed_in']){
                  gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
                    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                        'userId': 'me'
                    });
                    request.execute(function(resp){
                        $scope.$apply(function(){

                           //

                        });
                    });
                 }); 
               }
            },
            'scope':'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
        };
        gapi.auth.signIn(params);
   };
```